# Where are vim compound (dotted) filetypes documented

Tags: filetype

Vim has some kind of support for dot-separated compound filetypes like "ruby.rspec" where settings/definitions for both will be loaded. I see mentions of it around the internet but I can't find any mention of it in the docs. Is there a canonical doc on it or an official name for this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described briefly at `:h 'filetype'`:

```
When a dot appears in the value then this separates two filetype
names.  Example:
    /* vim: set filetype=c.doxygen : */ ~
This will use the "c" filetype first, then the "doxygen" filetype.
```

Comment: Huh, I kept scanning through the whole `:h filetype` page and searching for different terms w/o finding it.

Comment: @MuMind: the single quotes are significant. You get different pages with `:h filetype` and `:h 'filetype'`.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Yep, I know. `:h filetype` is the large in-depth doc where I expected to find details.