# Add current directory to UltiSnips search directory

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I want to have some specific snippets for each file that I am editing. Like, I want to type "ppp" just for "proper point groups", or "iff" for "if and only if".

To be more specific, I want **an additional unique set of snippets for each file** I am editing. For example, when I write about group theory, I will want things like above to be shorthanded. But when I write about geometry, I will want "hom" stands for "\operatorname{\mathcal{Hom}}", etc.

So far I succeeded to add a absolute path to UltiSnips search directory, like the following in my VIMRC:

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=['UltiSnips','C:\Users\xxx\Drafts\UltiSnips']
```

I tried to add an relative path like

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=['UltiSnips','.\UltiSnips']
```

But UltiSnips just ignores it. Any ideas?

Or, can I add a modeline to get the current directory, and then set the variable `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories`?

FYI.: I am on windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all [`:h UltiSnips-snippet-search-path`](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L372-L374) tells us:

> Snippet definition files are stored in snippet directories. A snippet
>   directory must be a subdirectory of a directory defined in the 'runtimepath'
>   option.

Which makes me think that you can not create snippets directories anywhere since that would mean constantly add your current path to `runtimepath` which doesn't sound like a good idea.

Thus I would advise the following solution: Use one directory containing your customs snippets, in this directory create snippets for "custom" filetype and add these files types to the files you want to edit (As both Vim and Ultisnips handle [multiple filetypes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4940/1841) that shouldn't cause a problem).

For example:

- Use your current snippets directory `'C:\Users\xxx\Drafts\UltiSnips'`
- In it, put files named `custom1.snippets` containing the snippets you want to use in the files which will use the `ppp` snippets.
- Then you can use `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes` ([here is the doc](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L223)) to select the snippets used in your file.

---

**Edit** (After the answer was accepted)

Another option could be the following: I didn't test it and it is based on my understanding of the doc so it may not work:

The same doc topic also says:

> If you keep your snippets in a .vim subdirectory called
>   "mycoolsnippets" and you want to make use of the default snippets that come
>   with UltiSnips, add the following to your vimrc file.
>
> ```
> let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips", "mycoolsnippets"]
> ```
>
> If you do not want to use the third party snippets that come with plugins,
>   define the variable accordingly:
>
> ```
> let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["mycoolsnippets"]
> ```
>
> **You can also redefine the search path on a buffer by buffer basis by setting
>   the variable `b:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories`. This variable takes precedence
>   over the global variable.**

So maybe (emphasis on maybe) you could:

- Create several snippets directories `project1`, `project2` at the same level as the `UltiSnips` directory.
- Each of these directories would contain differents snippets files for different filetypes in different projects.
- Then based on the project your file belongs to you could `let b:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["project1"]`

I think that this way you wouldn't need to play with the filetypes nor the `runtimepath` You simply would need to modify `b:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories` which should be done manually for each buffer because `let` is prohibited on modelines.

**Note** That as I said previously I didn't test that so I may be missing something.

Comment: Er... *proper point group* is not a filetype, is just a phrase that I want to abbreviate using UltiSnips. Then, can I use modeline  to get the current directory and set the value for `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories`. How do I do that?

Comment: @taper From [`UltiSnips-snippet-search-path`](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L372-L374) `Snippet definition files are stored in snippet directories. A snippet directory must be a subdirectory of a directory defined in the 'runtimepath' option.`. I don't think it is possible to use any project directory. That's why I suggested that you define filetypes grouping you custom snippets and that you set the desired filetype to the files you edit.

Comment: I get your point. That's a clever way to circumvent that restriction. Thanks!

Comment: @taper Nice, I'll edit my answer to make it clearer

Comment: `let` is prohibited in `modeline`. So, to make the second suggestion work one has to extend the built-in `modeline` by plugins like [let-modeline](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=83), or use a local `.vimrc` file. Both are, actually, a bit troublesome. :P

Comment: @taper Yup setting it manually is the best option then